# Box-Cox transformation for mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, data-transformation

Does there exists a Box-Cox method for linear Gaussian models with random effects ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at the web (e.g. google) always helps

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375804001235

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-985X.2005.00391.x/abstract

Of course,  linear Gaussian models with random effects is a huge topic.

Comment: Of course I spent some time to take a look at the web. I did not find this paper by Gurka & al which quite seems to adress the problem, thanks !

Comment: I have skimmed through the papers but find them very hard to follow, being not a statistician. Any advice how can one compute box cox for mixed models in R?