# Box-Cox transformation for repeated measures ANOVA (rANOVA) in R

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, data-transformation

**My proposition of the solution**

> Perform Box-Cox-transformation despite of knowledge that obeservations are nont independent and then use rANOVA to estiamte coefficients using the knowledge that the observations come from repeated measures design

**What is ANOVA?**

One might treat basic one-way (with one discrete explanatory variable) [Analysis of Varianace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) (ANOVA) model as a special case of a linear model with one discrete explanatory variable.

ANOVA estimates the difference of the mean of response variable between the levels of explanatory variable, and returns the F-statistics (based on variances, hence the name) from which one might infer the statistical significance of estimated differences (that are treated as coefficients in linear model, for suitable variable coding).

**Why do we use Box-Cox transformation?**

Due to the form of F-statistic, the assumption of independence, normality and homogeneity of the variances of the residuals is required. Those assumptions are often not satisfied, and one might perform [Box-Cox transformation](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/box-cox.html), using the full model, to transform the response variable to have more `normal`-like distribution.

**Problem: Repeated Measures**

Sometimes one might hit on a study that is design for repeated measures, and then the special `Error` stratum is required to take into account the blocked nature of a model. Hence, the repeated measure ANOVA can be performed (rANOVA), but as usual one can encounter non-normal distribution situation.

Dealing with repeated measures looks like to be a solved mathematical problem, moreover statistics is equiped in `Box-Cox` transformation when normality assumption is not fulfilled so one also has a tool to deal with non-normality. But what if a design is blocked, we encounter a repeated measures type of observations and response variable does not come from normal distribution.

**Question**

**Then one should perform Box-Cox tranformation for the repeated measures Analysis of Variance (rANOVA),** but it does not seem to be implemented in R statistical package.

I've tried myself to have a look at the implementation of `MASS::boxcox` function (https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/boxcox.R), but there only appear a method for standard `aov` (analysis of variance) that is treaten as a linear model (`lm` class). For repeated measures ANOVA (class `aovlist`) R below example does not work

```
> npk.aov <- aov(yield ~  N*P*K, npk)
> boxcox(npk.aov)
> npk.aovE <- aov(yield ~  N + Error(block), npk)
> boxcox(npk.aovE)
Error in boxcox.default(npk.aovE) : 
  ‘npk.aovE’ does not have both 'qr' and 'y' components
> boxcox(npk.aovE[[3]])
Error in update.default(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...) : 
  need an object with call component
> npk.aovE[[3]]$y <- npk$yield
> boxcox(npk.aovE[[3]])
Error in qr.resid(xqr, yt) : 
  'qr' and 'y' must have the same number of rows
```

beacuse of the `QR` decomposition matrix has only 18 rows

```
> nrow(npk.aovE[[3]]$qr$qr)
[1] 18
> NROW(npk.aovE[[3]]$y)
[1] 24
```

Does anyone know how to implement such alghoritm or have seen any package containing Box-Cox tranformation for repreatead measures ANOVA ?? I have seen Friedman's approach, which is an equivalent for Kruskal-Wallis test (non-parametric ANOVA) for repeated measures type of observations, and even the post-hoc tests implemented by Tal Galili (http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/02/post-hoc-analysis-for-friedmans-test-r-code/) but this approach is not sufficient for me since I will not obtain the linear model coefficients with a rank test, which Friedman's test is - I am most intersted in knowing what's the difference between groups in the explanatory variable. Maybe one could propose a differet approach than Box-Cox transformation for repreated measures ANOVA (rANOVA) ?

Comment: You should go for the modern way of doing repeated measurements, which is linear mixed models. Here is a relevant paper:  http://www.jstor.org/stable/3559673?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents    and a related Cross Validated post:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138766/box-cox-for-mixed-models-in-r   (so far unanswered).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks! I'll have a look and go deeper with this tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kjetil b halvorsen suggests I would go with linear mixed models: here are relevant [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3559673?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138766/box-cox-for-mixed-models-in-r) .